# Constructores de una plantilla

Tags: c++, template

Un patrón de diseño no excesivamente conocido es el patrón PassKey que se usa principalmente para restringir el acceso a determinadas funciones públicas (la opción sería usar friend en las clases principales y eso produce demasiado acoplamiento).

Una implementación básica podría ser:

```
template<class T>
class PassKey
{
  friend T;

  PassKey()
  { }

  PassKey(PassKey const&)
  { }

  PassKey& operator=(PassKey const&) = delete;
};
```

Nota que todos los elementos son privados... la gracia está en que únicamente el tipo `T` será capaz de crear objetos de este tipo. Un ejemplo de uso para verlo mejor:

```
class Objeto
{
public:

  // Puede ser llamada por cualquiera
  void FuncionPublica()
  { }

  // Solo Autorizado puede llamar a esta funcion
  void FuncionRestringida(PassKey<Autorizado>)
  { }

private:

  // Nadie puede llamar a esta funcion
  void FuncionPrivada()
  { }
};

class Autorizado
{
public:

  void Func(Objeto& obj)
  {
    obj.FuncionPublica(); // ok
    obj.FuncionRestringida(PassKey<Autorizado>()); // ok
    obj.FuncionPrivada(); // error de compilacion -> esperado
  }
};


class Espia
{
public:

  void Func(Objeto& obj)
  {
    obj.FuncionPublica(); // ok
    obj.FuncionRestringida(PassKey<Autorizado>()); // error de compilacion
    obj.FuncionRestringida(PassKey<Espia>()); // error de compilacion
    obj.FuncionPrivada(); // error de compilacion -> esperado
  }
};
```

Pues bien, ahora que ya está explicado el contexto vamos al lío. Ahora resulta que `Objeto.FuncionRestringida()` tiene que ser accedido por dos clases diferentes:

```
class Objeto
{
public:

  // Solo Autorizado y OtraClase pueden llamar a esta funcion
  void FuncionRestringida(PassKey<Autorizado,OtraClase>);

};
```

... en teoría el problema no reviste demasiada dificultad... basta con ampliar la plantilla. veamos:

**version1**

La plantilla ahora admite dos tipos:

```
template<class T1, class T2 = void>
class PassKey
{
  friend T1;
  friend T2;

  PassKey()
  { }

  PassKey(PassKey const&)
  { }

  PassKey& operator=(PassKey const&) = delete;
};
```

Problema... el constructor copia requiere que el objeto recibido sea de tipo `PassKey<Autorizado,OtraClase>`, lo cual obliga a modificar tanto `Autorizado` como `OtraClase` para que creen el objeto del tipo correcto... demasiado engorroso:

```
class Autorizado
{
public:

  void Func(Objeto& obj)
  {
    obj.FuncionRestringida(PassKey<Autorizado,OtraClase>()); // ok pero engorroso..
    obj.FuncionRestringida(PassKey<OtraClase,Autorizado>()); // error de compilacion
  }
};
```

La idea debería ser que cada uno se preocupe de crear una llave con su tipo y crear algun mecanismo que haga las conversiones pertinentes:

```
PassKey<T1> -> PassKey<T1,T2>
PassKey<T2> -> PassKey<T1,T2>
```

**version 2**

Intentamos sobrecargar los constructores para hacer las conversiones:

```
template<class T1, class T2 = void>
class PassKey
{
  friend T1;
  friend T2;

  PassKey()
  { }

  PassKey(PassKey const&)
  { }

  PassKey(PassKey<T1> const&)
  { }

  PassKey(PassKey<T2> const&)
  { }

  PassKey& operator=(PassKey const&) = delete;
};
```

Problema... se producen errores de compilación:

```
error: multiple overloads of 'PassKey' instantiate to the same signature 'void (const PassKey<Autorizado> &)'
  PassKey(PassKey<T1> const&)
  ^
note: in instantiation of template class 'PassKey<Autorizado, void>' requested here
    obj.FuncionRestringida(PassKey<Autorizado>());
                       ^
note: previous declaration is here
  PassKey(PassKey const&)
  ^
error: multiple overloads of 'PassKey' instantiate to the same signature 'void (const PassKey<OtraClase> &)'
  PassKey(PassKey<T1> const&)
  ^
note: in instantiation of template class 'PassKey<OtraClase, void>' requested here
    obj.FuncionRestringida(PassKey<OtraClase>());
                       ^
note: previous declaration is here
  PassKey(PassKey const&)
error: 'PassKey<T1, T2>::PassKey(const PassKey<T2>&) [with T1 = void; T2 = void]' cannot be overloaded
error: with 'PassKey<T1, T2>::PassKey(const PassKey<T1>&) [with T1 = void; T2 = void]'
In member function 'void Autorizado::Func(Objeto&)':
error:   initializing argument 1 of 'void Objeto::FuncionRestringida(PassKey<Autorizado>)'
```

Llegados a este punto... ¿hay solución al problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El primer problema en este caso es que existe una posible función duplicada:

```
template<class T1, class T2 = void>
class PassKey
{
  friend T1;
  friend T2;

  PassKey(PassKey const&) // 1
  { }

  PassKey(PassKey<T1> const&) // 2
  { }
};
```

¿Qué sucede cuando se ejecuta esta línea?:

```
class Autorizado
{
  // ...
  obj.FuncionRestringida(PassKey<Autorizado>());
  // ...
};
```

Se intenta instanciar un objeto de tipo `PassKey<Autorizado,void>`, lo que resulta en la siguiente interfaz:

```
class PassKey<Autorizado,void>
{
  PassKey(PassKey<Autorizado,void> const&) // 1
  { }

  PassKey(PassKey<Autorizado,void> const&) // 2
  { }
};
```

El constructor copia produce una duplicidad que no es admitida por el compilador. No es sencillo deshabilitar el constructor copia en base a `T1` y `T2`... y dada la finalidad de este objeto (llave de usar y tirar) lo más sensato es eliminar el constructor copia:

```
template<class T1, class T2 = void>
class PassKey
{
  friend T1;
  friend T2;

  PassKey()
  { }

  PassKey(PassKey<T1> const&)
  { }

  PassKey(PassKey<T2> const&)
  { }

  PassKey& operator=(PassKey const&) = delete;
};
```

Ahora, dependiendo del compilador elegido, la solución puede compilar o no. Algunos compiladores tienen problemas a la hora de resolver el problema comentado en la pregunta...

> error: 'PassKey::PassKey(const PassKey&) [with T1 = void; T2 = void]' cannot be overloaded

¿De donde sale ese `T1 = void; T2 = void`?

Quizás no es algo que se observe a primera vista pero ahí está. El siguiente objeto:

```
PassKey<Autorizado>();
```

Posee la siguiente interfaz:

```
class PassKey<Autorizado>
{
  PassKey()
  { }

  PassKey(PassKey<Autorizado> const&)
  { }

  PassKey(PassKey<void> const&)
  { }

  PassKey& operator=(PassKey const&) = delete;
};
```

Si expandimos las plantillas poniendo **ambos** tipos de forma explícita:

```
class PassKey<Autorizado,void>
{
  PassKey()
  { }

  PassKey(PassKey<Autorizado,void> const&)
  { }

  PassKey(PassKey<void,void> const&) // <<--- AQUI!!!
  { }

  PassKey& operator=(PassKey const&) = delete;
};
```

Y voilá, ya hemos encontrado la implementación `T1 = void; T2 = void`, pero... ¿Dónde está el problema?

Si revisamos la implementación de la especialización `<void,void>`, tenemos lo siguiente:

```
class PassKey<void,void>
{
  PassKey(PassKey<void,void> const&) // 1
  { }

  PassKey(PassKey<void,void> const&) // 2
  { }
};
```

Espera... ¿de dónde salen estos dos constructores si este problema ya lo habíamos corregido al principio?

Veamos nuestra implementación actual de la plantilla:

```
template<class T1, class T2 = void>
class PassKey
{
  friend T1;
  friend T2;

  PassKey()
  { }

  PassKey(PassKey<T1> const&) // 1
  { }

  PassKey(PassKey<T2> const&) // 2
  { }

  PassKey& operator=(PassKey const&) = delete;
};
```

El error viene por los dos constructores comentados. Al ser `T1 = T2` ambos constructores pasan a ser iguales. Este problema se soluciona creando una especialización para `<void,void>` que elimine esta ambigüedad:

```
template<>
class PassKey<void,void>
{
  PassKey();

  PassKey(PassKey const&);

  PassKey& operator=(PassKey const&) = delete;
};
```

Aunque también podemos optar por crear una solución un poco más genérica:

```
template<class T>
class PassKey<T,T>
{
  friend class T;

  PassKey();

  PassKey(PassKey const&);

  PassKey& operator=(PassKey const&) = delete;
};
```

Y con esto ya conseguimos sortear todos los problemas de una solución tan aparentemente sencilla como la planteada en la pregunta.